# Conditional redirect in .htaccess file for double .html

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, conditional-statements, redirect

I am trying to add condition in the htaccess file for double .html URL's.

Please see the below url:

```
http://example.com/test-page.html.html
```

It should redirect to the below url:

```
http://example.com/test-page.html
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Redirect in your htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)\.html\.html$ /$1.html
```

This will redirect **/file.html.html** to **/file.html** .